# Command which do not locate the real path of command

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, locate, which

We have a RHEL 7.x with Hortonworks (HDP) installed and need an advice why we get on `which` command:

> no hadoop in ...

The Hadoop client is installed under `/usr/bin` and from `env` we get

```
[root@hadoop_machine ~]# env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

as it should be. So why we get on `which hadoop` this error?

```
[root@hadoop_machine ~]# which hadoop
/usr/bin/which: no hadoop in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

[root@hadoop_machine ~]# ls -ltr /usr/bin | grep hadoop
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         44 Jun  4 11:24 yarn -> /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/bin/yarn
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         51 Jun  4 11:24 mapred -> /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/bin/mapred
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         44 Jun  4 11:24 hdfs -> /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/bin/hdfs
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         41 Jun  4 11:24 hadoop -> /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/bin/hadoop
```

Comment: The hadoop program in /usr/bin is a symbolic link. Does the endpoint of that link exist?

Comment: yes you absolutely right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hadoop` executable in `/usr/bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/bin/hadoop`.  It is likely that the target for that symbolic link does not exist. If it exists, one should investigate it to make sure that it is executable.

`which` would not display it if the symbolic link was pointing to a file that was either missing (a dead symbolic link), or not executable.

Also, it's generally better to use `command -v` rather than `which` (especially in scripts that should be portable).

Related:

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249)